# How to add dynamic vector image to imageview in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, imageview

I want access to vector image without loops.How can I make dynamic file adress? I tried something like this but not working. What can I do ?

```
    String img="R.drawable."+cryptoList.get(position).getSymbol().toLowerCase();
    imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(img));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the image view with vector much easier then that :

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vectorName);
```